# GWT in eclipse Compile error

Tags: eclipse, gwt

This is not really an error but I'm trying to find out how to tell the GWT compiler to put the generated files in folder xx/yyinstead of the default  ModuleName/ModulaName+Package that it currently puts them in

```
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#DevGuideCompilerOptions
```

is not really of any help as can't see how to add the configuration parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hilbrand,  Thanks but the issue I was having was how to pass the parameters to the GWT compiler when running it in eclipse.  I didn't really explain it properly in my question.
Anyways for anyones who stumble on this question here is the solution

http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/gwt-compiler-options/

Its in the advanced option when you launch the GWT Compile command in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The `-war` option allows you to specify were the output files are generated. The directory name of the generated files in this directory is by default the package + module name. You can specify another name by setting this in your module .gwt.xml file: `<module rename-to="somename">` where `somename` will be the name of the directory. The first reference of ModuleName in `ModuleName/ModulaName+Package` is the deployment name. The name is the url set in the GWT tab of you devmode debug configuration.